# How do I prove these estimates from number theory?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

A note I'm reading currently (the note itself deals with a novel way of estimating the number of square-free integers up to, say, $z$) uses without proof the following estimates:

(i) If $f(n)=n^2\prod_{p|n}(1-\frac{1}{p^2})$, then $\sum_{d|n}f(d)=n^2$

(ii) $\zeta(2)-\frac{1}{z}\leq \sum_{n\leq z}\frac{\mu(n)^2}{f(n)}\leq\zeta(2)$.

I can't figure out a way to obtain any of these estimates. Are they even related to each other in some way? I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: I think the bound is correct. Whether it's elementary or not, I don't know.

Comment: I made an error for the lower bound.. I can show that $\sum_{n \le x} \frac{1}{f(n)} \ge \zeta(2) - \frac{1}{x}$..not the same

Answer (score 1):

The first proposition can be proved using the same proof of $$\frac{\phi\left(n\right)}{n}=\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)
 $$ (it can be found in the Apostol's book). Assume that $p_{1},\dots,p_{r}
 $ are the prime divisors of $n
 $. Then note that the product can be writte as $$\prod_{i=1}^{r}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_{i}^{2}}\right)=1-\sum\frac{1}{p_{i}^{2}}+\sum\frac{1}{p_{i}^{2}p_{j}^{2}}+\dots+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{r}}{p_{i}^{2}\cdots p_{r}^{2}}
 $$ where every sum is understood that we consider all the possibile product of distinct prime factors of $n$. So it is not difficul to see that $$ f\left(n\right)=n^{2}\prod_{i=1}^{r}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_{i}^{2}}\right)=\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{n^{2}}{d^{2}}\mu\left(d\right)
 $$ and so the claim $(i)$ follows using the [Möbius inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula). About the proposition $(ii)$, the upper bound has been well explained by user1952009.

**Update: 04/12/2017**

Some ideas for the lower bound. Let $z \geq 2$ and $P\left(z\right)=\prod_{p\leq z}p$, $p$ prime number. Then we have $$\sum_{n\leq z}\frac{\mu^{2}\left(n\right)}{f\left(n\right)}=\sum_{\underset{{\scriptstyle n\mid P\left(z\right)}}{n\leq z}}\frac{1}{f\left(n\right)}\leq\sum_{n\mid P\left(z\right)}\frac{1}{f\left(n\right)}=\frac{1}{\prod_{p\leq z}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{2}}\right)}$$ hence, taking $t>0$, we have $$\frac{1}{\prod_{p\leq z}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{2}}\right)}-\sum_{n\leq z}\frac{\mu^{2}\left(n\right)}{f\left(n\right)}=\sum_{\underset{{\scriptstyle n\mid P\left(z\right)}}{n>z}}\frac{1}{f\left(n\right)}\leq\frac{1}{z^{t}}\sum_{\underset{{\scriptstyle n\mid P\left(z\right)}}{n>z}}\frac{n^{t}}{f\left(n\right)}$$ $$\leq \frac{1}{z^{t}}\prod_{p\leq z}\left(1+\frac{1}{p^{2-t}\left(1-1/p^{2}\right)}\right).$$ Unfortunately the choice $t=1$ doesn't work but maybe a clever choice can be done. Now I haven't much time but I will work on it. Furthermore it is possible to prove, using sieve theoretic arguments, that for any $\lambda >0$ we have $$\sum_{d\leq z}\frac{\mu^{2}\left(d\right)}{f\left(d\right)}\geq\frac{1}{\prod_{p<z}\left(1-1/p^{2}\right)\left(1+O\left(\exp\left(-\lambda+\left(\frac{C}{\lambda}+\frac{D}{\log\left(z\right)}\right)e^{\lambda}\right)\right)\right)}$$ where $C,D>0$ are suitable positive constants and $z \geq 2.$

Comment: I'm not entirely happy with my argument, but here goes: We need to establish $$\sum_{\operatorname{rad} k > z} \frac{1}{k^2} \leqslant \frac{1}{z}$$ for $z \geqslant 2$ (the inequality fails for $\frac{1}{2} < \frac{1}{z} < \zeta(2) - 1$). An elementary estimate gives $$\sum_{k > z} \frac{1}{k^2} < \frac{1}{\lfloor z\rfloor + \frac{1}{2}}.$$ That already settles it for $\{z\} \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$. Generally, it suffices to show $$\sum_{\substack{k > z \\ \operatorname{rad} k \leqslant z}} \frac{1}{k^2} \geqslant \frac{1}{\lfloor z\rfloor + \frac{1}{2}} - \frac{1}{\lfloor z\rfloor + 1}\,,$$

Comment: since the right hand side is $> \frac{1}{\lfloor z\rfloor + 1/2} - \frac{1}{z}$. Now $$\frac{1}{\lfloor z\rfloor + \frac{1}{2}} - \frac{1}{\lfloor z\rfloor + 1} = \frac{1}{(\lfloor z\rfloor + 1)(2\lfloor z\rfloor + 1)} < \frac{1}{2\lfloor z\rfloor^2}\,.$$ Next, consider a prime $p \leqslant z$, and let $m$ so that $p^m \leqslant z < p^{m+1}$. Then $$\sum_{\substack{k > z \\\operatorname{rad} k = p}} \frac{1}{k^2} = \sum_{n = m+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p^{2n}} = \frac{1}{(p^2-1)p^{2m}} \geqslant \frac{1}{(p^2-1)\lfloor z\rfloor^2}\,.$$

Comment: Thus we're home for those $z$ such that $$\sum_{p \leqslant z} \frac{1}{p^2-1} \geqslant \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2^2-1} + \frac{1}{3^2-1} + \frac{1}{5^2-1}\,,$$ i.e. $z \geqslant 5$. The cases $2 < z < 3$ and $3 < z < 5$ are shown by inspection, $$\frac{1}{f(1)} + \frac{1}{f(2)} = \frac{4}{3} = \frac{5}{3} - \frac{1}{3} > \zeta(2) - \frac{1}{3}$$ and $$\frac{1}{f(1)} + \frac{1}{f(2)} + \frac{1}{f(3)} = \frac{35}{24} = \frac{199}{120} - \frac{1}{5} > \zeta(2) - \frac{1}{5}\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $h(n) = \frac{f(n)}{n^2} = \prod_{p | n} h(p)$ then $h(n)$ is multiplicative, so that $f(n)=h(n)n^2$ and $g(n) = \frac{\mu(n)^2}{f(n)}$ are multiplicative too.

Thus, since $g(p)=\frac{\mu(p)^2}{f(p)} = \frac{1}{p^2-1}$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty g(n)= \prod_p (1+\sum_{k \ge 1}g(p^k)) = \prod_p (1+\frac{1}{p^2-1}) = \prod_p \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p^2}} = \zeta(2)$$

i.e.
$$\sum_{n \le x} g(n) \le \zeta(2)$$

Then for the lower bound, you have to show that $\sum_{n=k}^\infty g(n) \le \int_k^\infty \frac{dt}{t^2} = \frac{1}{k}$
$\color{red}{\text{I have no idea how}}$

Comment: Note that $$\frac{\mu(n)^2}{f(n)} = \sum_{\operatorname{rad} k = n} \frac{1}{k^2},$$ so $$0 < \zeta(2) - \sum_{n \leqslant z} \frac{\mu(n)^2}{f(n)} = \sum_{\operatorname{rad} k > z} \frac{1}{k^2} < \sum_{k > z} \frac{1}{k^2}.$$ That last expression is a bit too large when $z$ is a little smaller than an integer, but a slightly more conservative estimate should give $\frac{1}{z}$. (cc @MarcoCantarini)